# Atrix 4G update via OTA with unlocked bootloader?

Tags: bootloader, ota-update, bootloader-lock, motorola-atrix-4g

I am running 4.5.91 currently on a rooted and unlocked Atrix.

Will I brick my phone by updating to 4.5.141 from OTA source?

Can I re-lock the boot-loader if that is the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to re-lock the bootloader of a Atrix 4G. You should read [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1211198)
too

Comment: I found out as much. Ended up flashing an AOSP ROM (nottatch or something) and it's wonderful. It was built off of 4.5.141 so problem solved.

Comment: oh ok good to hear :)